# How update the hour element of a lubridate object when i sum minutes surpassing 59M?

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to add any quantity of minutes to a `Period` variable, and i'd like the hour element update whenever the minute element exceeds 59. In the following operation, the additive works well for the first example using this syntax, but in the second case it doesn't:

```
library(lubridate)
hm_example <- hm("17:49")

hm_example + minutes(10)
# [1] "17H 59M 0S"

hm_example + minutes(100)
# [1] "17H 149M 0S"
```

The second case i'd like the result as `19H 29M 0S`. I've seen the package documentation, but i couldn't find an alternative for this. Is there a native option from lubridate to correct it ?

I am using lubridate package of version `1.7.1` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with a little trick and the argument `roll = TRUE`.

```
temp <- hm_example + minutes(100)

hms(temp, roll = TRUE)
#[1] "19H 29M 0S"
```

Comment: You don't need `as.character` really.

Comment: You are right when using `hms`. Using `hm` will not work without `as.character`. It gives you `NA`.